# R inner join two table using sqldf package

Tags: r, join, sqldf

I have two data frames.

First Table:
[image]

And Secondtable:
[image]

Both tables have the same variable called `LaneSystemID` and both of them are `Char` type. After researching on the internet, I decided to use the `sqldf` this package to inner join two variables.

```
Firsttable.LaneSystemID=Secondtable.LaneSystemID
```

Below is my script to inner join two data frames:
1. Make Sql script as a string:

```
joinstring <-"select Firsttable.*,Secondtable.GANTRY_MILEAGE from Firsttable inner join Secondtable on Firsttable.LaneSystemID=Secondtable.LaneSystemID"
```

2. Join the two data frames into a new data frame:

```
df5 <-sqldf(joinstring, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

But `df5` has no observations
[image]

Below is my R version:

[image]

I want to join the two tables, because I need a column in Secondtable called `GANTRY_MILEAGE`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: try `inner_join` in `dplyr` package

Comment: Already tried dplyr, also cant inner join.

Comment: Do not use images when posting to SO.   Provide self contained mnimal reproducible code in copyable text form including all inputs like in the Note in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36553170/r-sqldf-renaming-a-field-in-a-select-statement  Also see [mcve] .

Comment: Thx for your suggestions